# Displaying specific json subarray values (arduino)

Tags: json, arduino, esp8266

Please bear with me as I'm new to most coding.

I'm trying to query an API for wind speed at different altitudes (3m and 500m in this example)

The script returns both values and I'd like to specify which value to display in serial. Since the api returns two arrays titled "parameter", I don't know how to differentiate them in code.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <Arduino_JSON.h>



const char* ssid = "**";
const char* password = "**";


// THE DEFAULT TIMER IS SET TO 10 SECONDS FOR TESTING PURPOSES
// For a final application, check the API call limits per hour/minute to avoid getting blocked/banned
unsigned long lastTime = 0;
// Timer set to 10 minutes (600000)
//unsigned long timerDelay = 600000;
// Set timer to 10 seconds (10000)
unsigned long timerDelay = 10000;

String jsonBuffer;

void setup() {
  // Stream& input;

  Serial.begin(9600);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("Connecting");
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to WiFi network with IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
 
  Serial.println("Timer set to 10 seconds (timerDelay variable), it will take 10 seconds before publishing the first reading.");
}


void loop() {
  // Send an HTTP GET request
  
  if ((millis() - lastTime) > timerDelay) {
    // Check WiFi connection status
    if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){
      String serverPath = "http://personal_presbrey:vfDmDSb956@api.meteomatics.com/2022-11-01T00:00:00Z/wind_speed_3m:mph,wind_speed_500m:mph/" + lat + "," + longs + "/json";
      
      jsonBuffer = httpGETRequest(serverPath.c_str());
      Serial.println(jsonBuffer);
      JSONVar myObject = JSON.parse(jsonBuffer);
  
      // JSON.typeof(jsonVar) can be used to get the type of the var
      if (JSON.typeof(myObject) == "undefined") {
        Serial.println("Parsing input failed!");
        return;
      }
      
      Serial.print("JSON object = ");
      Serial.println(myObject);
      //Serial.print("Temperature: ");
      //Serial.println(myObject["dates"]["values"]);
     
     
      
      //Serial.print("Pressure: ");
      //Serial.println(myObject["main"]["pressure"]);
      //Serial.print("Humidity: ");
      //Serial.println(myObject["main"]["humidity"]);
      //Serial.print("Wind Speed: ");
      //Serial.println(myObject["wind"]["speed"]);
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
    }
    lastTime = millis();
    StaticJsonDocument<768> doc;

DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, jsonBuffer);

if (error) {
  Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
  Serial.println(error.f_str());
  return;
}

const char* version = doc["version"]; // "3.0"
const char* user = doc["user"]; // "personal_presbrey"
const char* dateGenerated = doc["dateGenerated"]; // "2022-11-01T04:56:31Z"
const char* status = doc["status"]; // "OK"

for (JsonObject data_item : doc["data"].as<JsonArray>()) {

  const char* data_item_parameter = data_item["parameter"]; // "t_2m:C", "wind_speed_10000m:mph"

  JsonObject data_item_coordinates_0 = data_item["coordinates"][0];
  double data_item_coordinates_0_lat = data_item_coordinates_0["lat"]; // 26.430685, 26.430685
  double data_item_coordinates_0_lon = data_item_coordinates_0["lon"]; // -81.407801, -81.407801

  const char* data_item_coordinates_0_dates_0_date = data_item_coordinates_0["dates"][0]["date"];
  float data_item_coordinates_0_dates_0_value = data_item_coordinates_0["dates"][0]["value"]; // 25.5, ...
  
  Serial.println("Wind at 3m");
  Serial.println(data_item_coordinates_0_dates_0_value,6);
}
  }
}

String httpGETRequest(const char* serverName) {
  WiFiClient client;
  HTTPClient http;
    
  // Your IP address with path or Domain name with URL path 
  http.begin(client, serverName);
  
  // Send HTTP POST request
  int httpResponseCode = http.GET();
  
  String payload = "{}"; 
  
  if (httpResponseCode>0) {
    Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    payload = http.getString();
  }
  else {
    Serial.print("Error code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  }
  // Free resources
  http.end();

  return payload;
}
```

I checked json library and syntax and am at a loss

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In order for people to understand the problem you are facing, we need to know how exactly your JSON object looks like.

Comment: {"version":"3.0","user":"personal_presbrey","dateGenerated":"2022-11-02T07:52:05Z","status":"OK","data":[{"parameter":"wind_speed_3m:mph","coordinates":[{"lat":26.430685,"lon":-81.407801,"dates":[{"date":"2022-11-01T00:00:00Z","value":2.5}]}]},{"parameter":"wind_speed_500m:mph","coordinates":[{"lat":26.430685,"lon":-81.407801,"dates":[{"date":"2022-11-01T00:00:00Z","value":2.8}]}]}]}

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Other than some clean-up need to be done for some unused code and library, you code works as expected. You can replaced the two `Serial.println()` with this pieces of code `Serial.printf("Wind at %s\t %f\n", data_item_parameter, data_item_coordinates_0_dates_0_value);`.